# Magento same order mail sending for admin and customer

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When a new order is placed, the same mail copy is sending to both admin and the customer. I tried with different mail templates in the admin panel

Comment: can you describe what you are try to achive?

Comment: improve your question. it is unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?